# Unable to populate a CheckListBox with entries from a List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, checkboxlist, xceed

I have the following XML from where the ID is obtained and populated to the List:

```
<TestCase ID="TEST">
   <Frames>
     <Frame>ff</Frame>
     <Frame>ff 53</Frame>
   </Frames>
</TestCase>
```

I have created a `List` as follows:

```
public List<CheckedListItem> AvailableFrames;

public class CheckedListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

The Xaml where I have created the CheckListBox is as follows,

```
<xctk:CheckListBox x:Name="ListBox_TestCase"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}"
                   SelectedMemberPath="{Binding IsChecked}"
                   SelectedValue="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Here is how I have assigned the entries that are parsed from the XML to the `List` and then to the `CheckBoxList`:

```
private void Button_TestCase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
    try
    {
        TestCases1 = Serializer.Deserialize("TEST.xml");
        AvailableFrames = new List<CheckedListItem>();
        if (TestCases1 != null)
        {
            Int32 xx = 0;
            foreach (TestCase item in OSDPTestCases1.TestCases)
            {
                AvailableFrames.Add(new CheckedListItem() {Id = xx++, Name = item.ID, IsChecked = false });
            }
        }

        ListBox_TestCase.ItemsSource = AvailableFrames;    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var result = ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Error", btn);
    }
}
```

However I am not able to get the List `AvailableFrames` to populate the "Name" entries to the CheckBoxList items. It somehow takes the number of  entries (Which is 5 in my case) and populates 5 empty checkList items, but the Name or the value in "ID" is not reflecting.

Why are the values from the `List<AvailableFrames>` not coming up in the `CheckBoxList`? I am guessing that I have a binding issue.

Please advice.

ScreenShot:
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Did you take a look at the [example implementation](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer/Samples/CheckLists/Views/) by Xceed?

Comment: You mean the one here,

[WPF Example from Xceed](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckListBox&referringTitle=Home)

Yes, I did.

Comment: No, the one I linked in my comment. It's the live explorer demo of Xceeds WPF Toolkit.

Comment: Be sure that you implement Equals and GetHashCode methods. If not you could experience problems with the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "Modern UI" or mui does not support CheckListBox. When I removed the mui interface from my project I can get it to work fine.

We can also use make a ListBox with Checkboxes for each entry like below, which is supported by Modern UI.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_TestCase" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}" Margin="172,10,283,15" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_TestCase" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're populating the `SelectedMemberPath` and `SelectedValue` properties in the wrong way. Instead of using the `{Binding}` syntax, try the following:

```
<xctk:CheckListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}" SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ValueMemberPath="Id"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that did not help too.

`<xctk:CheckListBox x:Name="ListBox_TestCase" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="157,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}" SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked" ValueMemberPath="Name"/>`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up `ValueMemberPath` and `DisplayMemberPath`... Please see my updated answer, works for me!

Comment: And by the way, you can remove the `ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}"` part from XAML code, since you're setting the list box' `ItemSource` in code anyway... (however that should not affect the display issue, just as a side note)

Comment: There seems to be no difference, I am still getting an empty entry from the List.

`<xctk:CheckListBox x:Name="ListBox_TestCase" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="157,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}" SelectedMemberPath="IsChecked" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ValueMemberPath="Id"/>`

Comment: Well, it works fine for me with hardcoded items within the `List<AvailableFrames>`, so I'd suspect something goes wrong while populating the list from the XML file... Can you pls set a breakpoint at `ListBox_TestCase.ItemsSource = AvailableFrames;` and check the contents of `AvailableFrames`? Does it really contain 5 items, and do the `Name` properties of the 5 items contain string values?

Comment: I did try that, I can see that there are 5 entries in the "AvailableFrames" (Count=0x00000005). When I step in the watch, the 5 entries I see are "TestProj.Pages.CheckedListItem", then If I step in further, I can see 3 entries, "ID:0x000000, IsChecked:false, Name:TEST". I was thinking of this from start, is entries are not showing up because the value is actually "TestProj.Pages.CheckedListItem" instead of "Name" ?

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce that. Maybe you could once again try with static, hardcoded data (e.g., just `AvailableFrames = new List<CheckedListItem> { new CheckedListItem { Id = 1, IsChecked = true, Name = "A" } }; ListBox_TestCase.ItemsSource = AvailableFrames;`), check for typos in the XAML binding code, etc. With this example data, you should see one item that is checked and has caption 'A'

Comment: Ok.. I tried that and now I can see that one of the CheckBoxes (The first one) is Checked and Still no names in the CheckedList entries. I think it took, Ischecked=true from the below line, but not the Name. I also checked for typos for a longtime, let me do some more  research and see what comes up. :) 

`AvailableFrames = new List<CheckedListItem> { new CheckedListItem { Id = 1, IsChecked = true, Name = "A" } };`